# Trouble with Discrete Math proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

This seemingly easy proof is giving me some trouble..

For every number n $\in$ $Z$, if $n>n^2+1$ then $n\leq0$.

I find that proving the conditional statement P implies Q is false. For example $n=-2$, it is false that $-2>(-2)^2+1$.

But proving the contrapositive is true (not Q implies not P). If $n>0$ then $n\leq n^2 +1$

Can someone point out where I might be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried sketching a graph of $n$ and $n^2+1$?

Comment: Mark - Thank you, I didn't think of that. The statement seems true after all! P implies Q is a False implying anything, so the statement should be true which which is consistent now with the contrapositive being true. Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The statement given is false. Note that $n^2+1$ is strictly positive so if $n>n^2+1$ then $$n>n^2+1>0$$

Comment: Ok - but why does it seem the contrapositive is true? Did I state it correctly? For the contrapositive I would have the statement: $0<n<n^2+1$, which is true.

Comment: Daniel, you may want to reread the whole statement. @Justin, that's not quite the contrapositive.

Comment: The statement given in the problem is true, not false. Justin has written the reason why in a comment in his question.

Comment: But $n^2+1>0$... @MarkS. whatt am I missing here?

Comment: Certainly, $A>B>0$ always implies $A>0$. But does that mean it can't also imply $A\le0$?

Comment: But then we have $A \leq 0$ and $A>0$?

Comment: You have a logical statement $P \rightarrow Q$. Drawing the truth table for this, you will see that it is false precisely when $P$ is false and $Q$ is true. The big point in your answer is that $P$ is actually true. That makes $P \rightarrow Q$ vacuously true regardless of $Q$.